# Init a computed variable

Tags: swift, properties, var, computed-properties

I'm going to create a new class, and in this class there's a computed variable; so I'm looking for a way to init this variable:

```
import UIKit

class Squadra: NSCoder, NSCoding
{
    var nomeSquadra: String
    var numeroCoriSquadra: Int
    var coloreSquadra: String
    var immagineSquadra: String

    var sottotitoloSquadra: String
    {
        get
        {
            return "I migliori cori: \(nomeSquadra)"
        }
    }

    init(nome: String, numero: Int, colore: String, immagine: String, sottotitolo: String)
    {
        nomeSquadra = nome
        coloreSquadra = colore
        numeroCoriSquadra = numero
        immagineSquadra = immagine
        sottotitoloSquadra = sottotitolo
    }
}
```

obviously with this line of code Xcode gives my a compile error (because the var is a get only property).
I think that i have to use a set to make the var writable, but I don't know how to operate because I don't know exactly how get and set work.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove `sottotitoloSquadra = sottotitolo` or assign to a different variable.  Even if the assignment worked, you never actually use the value that comes in as `sottotitolo` for anything.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see useful behavior while you use independent property `nomeSquadra` and trying to have setter for `sottotitoloSquadra` at the same time. Maybe better to use hidden support property for computed variable in your case?

```
private var _sottotitoloSquadra: String
var sottotitoloSquadra: String
{
    get
    {
        return "I migliori cori: \(_sottotitoloSquadra)"
    }
    set
    {
        _sottotitoloSquadra = newValue
    }
}

init(nome: String, numero: Int, colore: String, immagine: String, sottotitolo: String)
{
    //...
    _sottotitoloSquadra = sottotitolo
}
```

Comment: This is close, but remember the sotto computed variable is meant to be read only, so better remove the set part. The init part is good.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you class correctly, you want to use the variable's default string when the init() did not provide a value (I'm just guessing though).

So if the team doesn't have a specific subTitle, you would make one up from the team's name.

I also understand that you don't want that property to be modifiable after the object is instantiated.

If that is the case, (I assume you would get an empty string for sottotitolo), you can define a private variable to hold the provided title and expose it using a computed variable.  The default value (made up title) can be returned by that computed variable if a title was not supplied on the init().

```
 class Squadra
 {
     var nomeSquadra: String
     var numeroCoriSquadra: Int
     var coloreSquadra: String
     var immagineSquadra: String

     private var _sottotitoloSquadra = ""  
     var sottotitoloSquadra: String 
     { 
       return _sottotitoloSquadra == "" 
            ? "I migliori cori: \(nomeSquadra)" 
            : _sottotitoloSquadra
     }

     init(nome: String, numero: Int, colore: String, immagine: String, sottotitolo: String)
     {
         nomeSquadra = nome
         coloreSquadra = colore
         numeroCoriSquadra = numero
         immagineSquadra = immagine
         _sottotitoloSquadra = sottotitolo
     }
 }
```

Only your class, including its init() function, can modify the private variable holding the supplied sottotitolo.  Outside of that source file, the private variable is not accessible at all.